# gimp command line

Tags: gimp

I am using gimp 2.6 in linux and would like to run a built in script from the command line (plugins > web > slice).  Using the default options would be fine, or entering in them at the command line would be fine I don't really care.  Just simply run the built-in script from the command line and then exit gimp.  But I can't find a simple example anywhere online, all of them huge scripts with very steep learning curves.  Could someone please give me an example of how to just run py-slice on an image and then exit the gimp?

Comment: You may be interested in a batch tutorial: http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/ One thing tou must keep in mind is that normal built in scripts don't take explicit file names as input: you need additional steps to open and save files.